¿Como ir una pagina en especifica de la paginacion en datatable?
Alguien sabe como puedo recorrer la paginación de mi datatable. Ejemplo solo me muestra de la página < 1 2 3 ... 100 111 >.
Pero ir a la página 50 me es muy complicado porque tengo que hacer 50 clics para llegar a la página 50, entonces no sé cómo hacer que al cargar ponga un input y diga "página", al ingresar 50 y enter y me lleva a la página 50. señalado en la parte de flecas qusiiera poder ir al pagina 50 sin tantos clic;
$('#tblArea').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: url + '/serverSide',
    columns: [
        {data: "id"},
        {data: "pantalla"},
        {data: "actu"},
        {data: "disco"},
        {data: "precioreal"},
        {data: "codigo"},
        {data: "procesador"},
        {data: "reintentos"},
        {data: "cEstatus"},
        {data: "status"},


    ],
    stateSave: true,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50,200, -1], [5, 10, 50, 200, "All"]],
});





El código como texto.

listo agrege el texto o el codigo

No es el texto o el código, es todo el código que compartas va como texto. Incluso cuando agregas una imagen te dice que no la uses para compartir código.

Como deberia quedar o no se como hacer el input mande el ajax para ir a la pagina 50 en la terce imagen agrege un ejemplo,

Solamente tienes que copiar y pegar el código en lugar de poner una imagen.

Ya probaste el plugin input paginación para Datatables? https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input

Puedes añadir un input y utilizar la función Page para agregar la funcionalidad requerida, incluso es posible incluir algo de validación para no ir a una página inexistente


let table;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",intit);
pageInput.addEventListener("change",paginate);

function intit(){
  table = new DataTable('#tabla',{ searching: false,  "bLengthChange": false, "bInfo": false});
  pageInput.setAttribute("max", table.page.info().pages);
  
  table.on("page", () =>{
    if(pageInput.valueAsNumber !== table.page.info().page+1)
        pageInput.valueAsNumber = table.page.info().page+1;
  }); 
}

function paginate(e){
  if(e.target.checkValidity()){
    table.page(e.target.valueAsNumber-1).draw('page');
  }
}
#pageInput:user-invalid {
  outline:1px solid red;

}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.8/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label>
Ingresa el Número de página
<input type="number" id="pageInput" value="1" step="1" min="1">
</label>


<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col A</th>
      <th>Col B</th>
      <th>Col C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <script>
      for(let i=0; i<100;i++){
        document.write(`<tr>
          <td>Fila ${i} col A</td>
          <td>Fila ${i} col B</td>
          <td>Fila ${i} col C</td>
        </tr>`);
      }
    </script>
  </tbody>
</table>




Por lo que puedo ver, para el método Page la numeración de las páginas va de 0 a n - 1. En usuariolandia, si escribes el número 1, en realidad te lleva a la página 2, y tienes que escribir 0 para que te lleve a la página 1.  Por otro lado, para mi como usuario también sería deseable que, si voy paginando con los controles que ofrece el DataTable, el número que se muestra en el input se vaya actualizando en concordancia.

@jachguate Vale, gracias por la corrección!! Estoy altamente condicionado para satisfacer los caprichos de los usuarios, así que también agregue lo último que señalas

Gracias @Yussef, pero, jaja, vamos, eso no era un capricho, jajaja. :D
